# Two identities with TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have two repositories where I want a different identity on each when I commit, can I configure it to pick an identify based on directory path or some sort?

I am on Windows use TortoiseGit and the identity can be specified in `Settings > GIT`

I see something about `"edit local .git/config"` is that what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can edit the local repositories `.git/config` file with these items to set local identity:

```
[user]
    email = <your email>
    name = <your name>
```

Answer (score 2):

In each project, right click Explorer context menu -> TortoiseGit -> Settings
In the treeview, select Git, enter name and email, click OK.
Then you may have independent name and email for each of the two repositories.
Make sure you select config source "local".

Comment: Should be updated for newer versions, for local vs. global